# google plus login gPlus id check?

Tags: javascript, php, google-plus

On the google developers serverflow documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

It says that you must validate the userid gotten from the server with the one send in by the client.

```
if ($tokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
    return new Response(
        "Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID", 401);
  }
```

However, I am not sure how the client javascript is supposed to know what the google id is. I'm pretty sure its now part of the callBack's authresult.

The only way I can think of is if the client itself made calls to google to get it's own googleid.

What is the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer** ( from my reading ) --

### gplus_Id authentication isn't needed and can leave that step

### Long Answer and references.

I found some answers during my readings. As it happens the java quick start application guide has the gplus_Id but the php one does not. Yet the single sign in flow is using it as you mention above ( in step 8 ). The google discussion [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=573) mentions that ---  " See the slightly related discussion here: https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-php/pull/7

The gplus_id is usually send from the client to the server together with the one-time code, but it doesn't really add anything in extra security, so it was removed from the php example.

But yeah, the documentation should be adjusted to match the current sample code.

(And the Java quickstart sample has been updated and doesn't send the gplus_id anymore either...)" .

I hope it helped :).